# How to add randomly noise with zero value in training data?

Tags: noise

```
    gt_array = [38.28,   236.86,    96.498,  187.41,   125.21,   131.59,   154.72,    78.156,
  198.58,    42.268,  121.22,   145.94,   157.11,   106.07,   196.98,    98.891,
  236.06,    94.903,  115.64,   177.05,   157.91,   157.11,   186.62,   147.54,
  224.9,    145.94,   115.64,   202.57,   161.1,    189.81,   189.81,   185.02,
  224.9,   183.43,   112.45,   228.88,   153.12,   236.86,   180.24,   241.64,
  204.96,   245.63]
```

I have this training data. I want to add zero value to some data in training to get better model with denoising. 
I know like this one:

```
noise_factor = 0.5
    input_noisy = gt_array + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc = 0.0, scale = 1.0 , size = gt_array.shape)
```

But I want to get randomly zero noise in training data? How can I do that?

Comment: What is the problem you have encountered with the above (like this one) expression?

Comment: actually I want to add zero value to training data randomly. I know how to add random noise to training data (like this one is sample add noise). I use np.random.normal in here. I want to get training data with zero value (not random value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use random choice to get a set of indices based on the proportion and
>   finally set those to 0.

```
zero_noise_proportion = 0.3 # 30% of the data
indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(gt_array.size), 
                           replace=False, 
                           size=int(gt_array.size * zero_noise_proportion))
gt_array[indices] = 0
```

Comment: Mr, I accepted your answer. But I would like to know one more thing. If I have data (50,42) rows and columns, I want to increase 0 proportion 0.3 to 0.5 for each row. How can I do that?

Comment: I cannot think of a one line answer to it. You can anytime iterate row by row and do it. Let me update here if I come across a better way to do that.